# Hide/Show box shadow on horizontal scroll bar movements

Tags: css

Is it possible to make the right box shadow to hide when the horizontal scroll bar reaches the end of the table and shadow should appear when the scroll bar is moved to the left hand side.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to react on scrollbar position or movement you will most likely need javascript.

If you post an example of your case (html/css) I might be able to give you a better answer :)